# Why does the Lagrangian of the electromagnetic vector potential has plus sign on the potential term?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, conventions

[image]

The given action $S$ on the above picture is said to give the Lorentz force law and electromagnetic field tensor. And $A_a$ is the covector which is the 4-vector potential. I am curious why the integral of the potential term has plus sign in front of it. $q$ is just the charge. For mechanics, lagrangian is $L=T-U$. Why does electromagnetism seem different? Could anyone please explain?

Comment: There is a convention of the action where it could get an overall minus sign that is originated from the signature of the metric. Please check what the metric signature is for that lecture note.

Comment: "L=T-U, U is potential energy" is valid only when U is position dependent only. Here magnetic vector energy is also speed dependent so different. See this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/420155/particle-in-electromagnetic-field-lagrangian?rq=1 and comments there. I agree that Lagrangian is just something that when differentiated yields the correct motion equation. It is not more fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, the velocity-dependent potential energy is 
$$U~=~q(\phi \dot{x}^0 -\vec{A}\cdot \dot{\vec{x}})~=~\mp q A_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu} ,$$

where

$$A^{\mu} ~=~(\phi,\vec{A} ), \qquad A_{\mu} ~=~(\mp \phi,\pm \vec{A} ), $$

in Minkowski signature $(\mp,\pm,\pm,\pm)$, respectively. (Here we work in units where $c=1$.)

Note in particular that the electric potential $\phi$ always comes with a plus sign in the  velocity-dependent potential energy $U$ (when the charge $q$ is positive).

Comment: Is $U$ the potential energy of a particle of charge $q$ obtained from the 4-vector potential $A_u$?