# Particle in electromagnetic field Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy

Given the two definitions of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ by scalar potential $\phi$ and vector potential $\vec A$:

$$\vec B=\vec \nabla \times \vec A$$
$$\vec E=-\vec \nabla \phi -\frac 1 c\frac {\partial \vec A} {\partial t}.$$

It is not so hard to show that the Lorentz force acting on a charged particle in the electric field is:

$$\vec F=Q\bigg(-\vec \nabla\phi-\frac 1 c \frac {d\vec A} {dt}+ \frac 1 c \vec \nabla(\vec v \cdot \vec A)\bigg).$$

After showing this part, several sources I've been looking at claim that the Lagrangian of that particle is given by:

$$L=\frac 1 2 mv^2 -Q\phi(\vec x, t)+\frac Q c\vec v \cdot \vec A$$

but I couldn't find a full derivation showing how you get this Lagrangian and two things bother me about it:

1) From my understanding, since the Lagrangian is defined as $L=T-V$ where $V$ is the potential energy and only related to the position, whereas in this Lagrangian $V$ is also velocity dependent.

2) Assuming I will try to make a line integral of the force from some arbitrary zero potential point to $\vec x$ while ignoring the velocity - it will indeed proved $L$'s $(-V)$ but with another term which relates to the $-\frac Q c \frac {d\vec A} {dt}$ part that is missing from $L$.

Can anybody please show a full derivation of the Lagrangian or explain what am I missing?

Comment: This is e.g. derived in Goldstein, Section 1.5.

Comment: The potential in a lagrangian is supposed to give us the forces. If any force is velocity dependent, the potential would need to be modified so as to produce the force in the equations.

Comment: @cobra121 I'm aware of that but it bugs me to think that this Lagrangian is just an "educated guess" that just in case gives us the correct force... That's why I want to see a derivation.

Comment: I am afraid that the only answer I can give is that it is indeed an educated guess... It just seems to be consistent with the previous results

Comment: @dani Well that's disappointing...

Comment: I am sorry I thought that i found a way of deriving it but I do not know how to show it without this guess! For the moment just to try to accept it, I hope somebody can help you out!

Comment: The only thing you can do is show that the Lagrangian gives the desired force that you claimed, then the Lagrangian describes the system. This is a derivation done in e.g. Goldstein.